# Installing Boost On Mac Issues

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

Has anyone had this issue on mac while installing boost or know how to fix? I seem to have everything together but this error. I am using OS X 10.10 & and Xcode 6.1.1.

This is what I used for the install and to make the framework.

http://freddy.cellcore.org/post/79587278354/boost-c-libraries-on-osx-xcode-5
https://gist.github.com/faithfracture/c629ae4c7168216a9856

-------------ERROR BELOW---------------

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(bool (*)(), int, char**)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Why don't you install it like in the official documentation? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html And where are you getting the error? When compiling boost? Or when trying your own program? In general, most programs using boost require only the header files, not the precompiled part (exceptions are boost::filesystem and some few others). Do you need a boost framework?

Comment: I have tried following it and like 20 different other tutorials that lead me to no where. Probably because all this path linking is new to me. I don't need a framework i just figured it would make life easier for me. It happens when i try to compile the test in Xcode on my program. @vsoftco